# How to watch for vuex mutations / actions from a component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I need to know whenever stuff happens across the page (e.g animations starting / finishing, requests firing / failing), etc and have a component react to it.

I can watch a `getter` easily by importing it thru `mapGetters` and watching it - can I do the same to e.g watch for actions / mutations firing? E.g if `requestFailed` event happens (and is fired via an action / commit), I can have my component (view) react to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a `plugin.js` file in store `directory`

in `plugin.js`

```
export function plugin(store) {
    //subscribe to mutations
    store.subscribe((mutations, state) => {

    })
    //subscribe to action
    store.subscribeAction({
        before(actions, state) {

        },
        after(actions, state) {

        },
    })
}
```

and then you can use your plugin in `index.js` as

```
//import plugins
import { plugin } from './plugins'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  namespaced: true,
  plugins: [plugin],
  modules: {
  }
})
```